# Nodejs: Uploading a stream to form-data results in 411 'Length-required'

Tags: node.js, form-data

I'm trying to upload a file to the storyblock API. This uses S3 behind the scenes. Local file uploads work, but when trying to fetch a file from an external URL I get a 411 error.

This works:

```js
    import { createReadStream } from 'fs'
    import FormData from 'form-data'
    
    const form = new FormData()
    form.append('file', createReadStream('./local-file.jpg))
    form.submit(...)
```

But when trying an external URL for the same file it doesn't:

```js
    import FormData from 'form-data'
    import got, { type Got } from 'got'
    
    const form = new FormData()
    form.append('file', got.stream(externalUrl, {decompress: false})
    form.submit(...)
```

Response:

```
  statusCode: 411,
  statusMessage: 'Length Required',
```

Which indicates that somehow got.stream() gives a different stream output than createReadStream()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Content-Length` header is missing that is why it's giving you `411`. The size of file being uploaded needs be determined and then include the `Content-Length` header in the request. Add this before submit.

```js
// Get the file size
const { headers } = await got.head(externalUrl);
const contentLength = headers['content-length'];
    
// Append the file to the form with the correct content length
form.append('file', stream, { knownLength: contentLength });
```